# I have no idea what this Typescript error mean

Tags: typescript

I have this button:

```
export interface ButtonProps {
    kind?: 'normal' | 'flat' | 'primary';
    negative?: boolean;
    size?: 'small' | 'big';
    spinner?: boolean;
}

export type ButtonPropsExtended = ButtonProps & React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement>;

class Button extends React.Component<ButtonPropsExtended> { ... }
```

I also have this sub-variant of that button:

```
import Button, { ButtonPropsExtended } from './button';

export interface CloseButtonProps extends ButtonPropsExtended {
    iconOnly?: boolean;
}

const CloseButton = ({ iconOnly, ...rest }: CloseButtonProps) => {
    return (
        <Button { ...rest }>
            { ...some jsx... }
        </Button>
    );
}
```

And I'm getting this massive Typescript error when I try to compile it all in strict mode:

```
ERROR in <my-dir>/button/close-button.tsx(14,10):
14:10 No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<ButtonPropsExtended>): Button', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; kind?: "normal" | "flat" | "primary" | undefined; negative?: boolean | undefined; size?: undefined; spinner?: boolean | undefined; accept?: string | undefined; ... 356 more ...; key?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicClassAttributes<Button>'.
      Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | ((instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLButtonElement> | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: Button | null) => void) | RefObject<Button> | null | undefined'.
          Type '(instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: Button | null) => void) | RefObject<Button> | null | undefined'.
            Type '(instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(instance: Button | null) => void'.
              Types of parameters 'instance' and 'instance' are incompatible.
                Type 'Button | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLButtonElement | null'.
                  Type 'Button' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLButtonElement': disabled, form, formAction, formEnctype, and 250 more.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ButtonPropsExtended, context?: any): Button', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; kind?: "normal" | "flat" | "primary" | undefined; negative?: boolean | undefined; size?: undefined; spinner?: boolean | undefined; accept?: string | undefined; ... 356 more ...; key?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicClassAttributes<Button>'.
      Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | ((instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLButtonElement> | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: Button | null) => void) | RefObject<Button> | null | undefined'.
          Type '(instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: Button | null) => void) | RefObject<Button> | null | undefined'.
            Type '(instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(instance: Button | null) => void'.
    12 | const CloseButton = ({ iconOnly, ...rest }: CloseButtonProps) => {
    13 |     return (
  > 14 |         <Button { ...rest }>
       |          ^
```

So my question is:

1. How do I fix this?

and

2. Are actual humans *actually* supposed to be able to read and comprehend these insane type check errors?

Comment: Please show the line of code with that error. close-button.tsx, line 14. That would help.

Comment: @AndreasDolk done

Comment: @o01 to answer 2. yes, hunans are supposed to be able to read and comprehend them; I've found it easiest to start at the bottom.

Comment: @OliverRadini How much does Microsoft pay you to spread such lies? 

Comment: @o01 ha they are a bit of bombshell when you first see them... but once you take a look into them they aren't so bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand what the actual error was, but it seems at least part of the problem was that `Button` was declared as a class component, while `CloseButton` was defined as a function component. So when I changed:

```js
class Button extends React.Component<ButtonPropsExtended> { ... }
```

to

```js
const Button = (props: ButtonPropsExtended) => { ... }
```

it worked fine.